# Where to download high resolution maps or layers for Greece?

Tags: data, imagery, maps, satellite, greece

I am trying to create management zones on selected fields in Greece, so I am looking for high-resolution layers (maps) to use as a base (preferably satellite imagery).

Could you suggest me the best sites to download high-resolution maps or layers of Greece?

Check attached picture of already known sites.

[image]

Comment: The national cadastre has a wms server with the imagery that is available on the web you could use as a basemap.

Comment: http://gis.ktimanet.gr/wms/wmsopen/wmsserver.aspx?, this is the wms server's address.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sentinel-2 imagery from ESA. Sentinel imagery has 10 m spatial resolution. You can see more details here:

https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi

And you can download data from Sentinel-2 imagery at here:

https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend earth explorer or eurostat

https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/de/data/bulkdownload

Comment: thank you for the suggestions Dirk. I already knew earthexplorer.usgs.gov but not the ec.europa.eu site. I will explore it today.